# i cannot store more than one value in an array

Tags: java

I am trying to create a program where in you can input your order and it remembers your orders and can display it if prompted. Problem is, I cannot seem to store more than one input for the history

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean a = true;
    int count = 0;
    String [] hist = new String [count+1];
for (int i = 0; a == true; i++)
    {
    //declaration
    String [] menu = {"1. Coke", "2. Sprite", "3. Lemonade", "4. History"};     
     //this should be outside of the loop i think

    //displays the menu
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        System.out.println(menu[j]);
    }

    //takes order
    System.out.println();
    int choice = sc.nextInt();

    //stores history
    if(choice != 4) 
    {
    hist[i] = menu[choice - 1];
    }

    //prints history
    else
    {
        for (int l = 0; l < hist.length; l++)
        {
            System.out.println("You have orderd; " + hist[l]);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Would you like to try again?");
    a = sc.nextBoolean();
    count++;
    }
```

Comment: `new String [count+1]` - this makes a String array of size 1.

Comment: You initalize your array with a size of 1.

Comment: The size of an array is fixed when you initialize it. If your `hist` can have arbitrary length, consider using an `ArrayList` instead.

Comment: thank you for pointing out my mistake!
I think I got it now
thanks a bunch

Comment: @DenMark: Please delete the question then.

Comment: @NicholasK I can't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it your problem is that Simple Arrays aren't variable in size meaning, once they're set to a certain length, new Values cannot be entered.

Example: if you have an Array of length 4 you can not store anything at index 4 or higher.

My preferred way of solving this would be using ArrayLists.

But you could also create a new Array each time:

```
//stores history
if(choice != 4){
    String temp = new String[hist.length];
    for(int x = 0; x < hist.length; x++){
        temp[x] = hist[x];
    }
    temp[hist.length] = menu[choice - 1];
    hist = temp;
}
```

You should also probably make it 
    if(choice < 4){...
Since that will check if choice is smaller than 4 and not if it just isn't 4.